# Подсчёт кол-во символов в PlainTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt

Как подсчитать кол-во символов введённых в поле `QPlainTextEdit`?
Я еще новичок в теме `QT` и в `С++` в целом, но кое что уже умею, иду на новые высоты)

Суть замысла такова, что мне нужно подсчитать кол-во введенных символов в поле `QPlainTextEdit` и вывести их значение в `QLabel`.

Нужно сделать в цикле `while` что бы выводило значение тут же, без нажатий кнопок.

Я пытался сделать так, понимаю что не правильно, можно и поругать)
Тут пока без получения данных из `QPlainTextEdit`. Для себя пытался.

```cpp
void MainWindow::on_plainTextEdit_textChanged()
{
    while (true)
    {
        QString s;
        s = "1";
        ui->label->setText(" " + s.length());
    }
}
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stackoverflow! Для начала, приведите свой код.

Comment: Как у Вас называется объект класса `QPlainTextEdit`?

Comment: Название объекта: plainTextEdit

Comment: Я полагаю, что `label` называется объект класса `QLabel`. А объект **класса `QPlainTextEdit`**, откуда берётся текст, называется как?

Comment: Исправил, запутался немного.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
void MainWindow::on_plainTextEdit_textChanged()
{
    int nums = ui->plainTextEdit->toPlainText().length();
    ui->label->setText(QString("Введено символов %1").arg(nums));
}
```

**PS.**

О форматировании строк через QString.arg: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#arg

Comment: Работает, спасибо большое)
А как из введенных символов выбрать нужный.
Например что-бы "%d" подсчитать за 1 символ?

Comment: @byte_, нужно будет вручную подсчитать. Возьмите строку из `ui->plainTextEdit->toPlainText()` и подсчитайте циклом символы по вашим правилам. Например, вы перебираете символы и встречаете `%` запоминаете это флагом пропускаете обработку, встречаете следующий символ и если он не `d`, то флаг снимаете, ставите `+2` к счетчику (за % и текущий символ), а если `d` то ставите `+1` (флаг снимаете). Еще можно регулярками задать правила поиска типа `"%d|."`, пример: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregexp.html#capturing-text

Answer (score 0):

1. У класса  `QPlainTextEdit` в Qt есть метод `toPlainText()`,
   возвращающий введённый текст в виде строки `QString`
2. У класса `QString`, в свою очередь, есть метод `size`, возвращающий
   число символов в строке

Если алгоритм действий всё ещё не ясен, поясню. Пусть у нас есть некий 
объект класса `QPlainTextEdit` под названием `textEd` и объект с названием `label`, в который нужно произвести вывод числа. Тогда следует сделать так:

```cpp
/* Точки при работе с указателями следует заменить на -> */
QString text = textEd.toPlainText();
int sizeOfText = text.size();
label.setText(sizeOfText);
```

Comment: Спасибо, можете подсказать как реализовать это?

Comment: @byte_ Пожалуйста, все свои попытки реализации вынесите в вопрос, как я уже попросил в комментариях. Там есть прекрасное средство подсветки кода, которое сделает всё понятнее, да и тем, кто в будущем будет гуглить такой вопрос, будет так полезнее.